# Adapt JSONField to have auto conversion to Decimal

Tags: json, django, django-1.10, django-postgresql, django-jsonfield

I have model with fields of type:

```
django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField
```

and I want have it always deserialized by:

```
json.loads(value, parse_int=decimal.Decimal, parse_float=decimal.Decimal)
```

when accessing objects by:

```
MyModel.objects.get(..)
```

however I found it hard to customize, because the line with `json.loads` which must be overriden by above one is in

```
psycopg2/_json.py
```

in inner method of `def _create_json_typecasters`.

so I am expecting to have to change my model fieldtype,
or maybe there is a easier way to tell Django how to prepare my model?

Answer (score 1):

I found it:

```
psycopg2.extras.register_default_json(loads=my_loads_func)
psycopg2.extras.register_default_jsonb(loads=my_loads_func)  # for Postgres jsonb
```

or adapting it in more sophisticated way:
[psycopg2 docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html?highlight=json#json-adaptation)